# Ruta PATH no responde en el servidor

Tags: php

Tengo un sitio en cual hay un archivo config.php que indica una ruta. En modo local funciona, pero cuando la subo a la web no.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0);

define('SITE_TITLE', 'Sitio Web');
define('SITE_PATH', '/public_html/'); //servidor en linea
//define('SITE_PATH', '/srv/http/sitiosWeb'); //localhost
define('SITE_PATH_ADMIN', SITE_PATH . '/admin');
define('SITE_PATH_CONFIG', SITE_PATH . '/config');
define('SITE_PATH_CONFIG_PROPEL', SITE_PATH . '/config/sturam-conf.php');
define('SITE_PATH_MODULES', SITE_PATH_ADMIN . '/modules');
define('SITE_DEBUG', false);

define('PROYECTO', 'Sturam');

require_once 'drivers.php';

session_start();
?>
```

Utilizo `piblic_html` porque es donde esta alojado el sitio o tengo que colocar una `url`?

Comment: Observa cómo defines `SITE_PATH`, así: `/public_html/`, **empieza con `/` y termina con `/`**. Luego, las otras constantes que usan a `SITE_PATH` también empiezan con `/`. Por ejemplo: `define('SITE_PATH_ADMIN', SITE_PATH . '/admin');` ¿Cuál es el resultado final: `/public_html/` + `/admin`, es decir, esto: **`/public_html//admin`** lo cual es una ruta incorrecta. Debes: o quitar el último `/` a `SITE_PATH` o quitar el primer `/` a todas las constantes que enlazan con él. Esto es muy fácil de ver con que hagas `echo SITE_PATH_ADMIN;` o `echo SITE_PATH_MODULES;`... verás que hay dos `//`

Comment: Gracuas @A.Cedano, hice los cambio y no funciona. Al principio fue que php no estaba actualizado, ahora lo han actualizado y la verdad no se que porque no funciona, en mi servidor local si. Habra alguna manera de saber si puede ser el servidor en donde esta alojado?

Comment: Para poder usar esas constantes debes incluir correctamente el archivo que las define. Por ejemplo: `include_once('config.php');`  sabiendo que debes poner la ruta completa donde se encuentre `config.php`. ¿Lo estás haciendo así?

Comment: Si, eso lo habia hecho en un principio hasta use `require_once(__DIR__.'/config/config-AP.php');` y nada, la ruta es correcta, porque en servidor local funciona bien

Comment: No asumas que la ruta es correcta porque sí. Si luego del include haces por ejemplo esto: `echo SITE_PATH_ADMIN;` ¿qué muestra en pantalla?

Comment: No me arroja ninguna ruta... en el servidor local, si, esta: `/srv/http/sitiosWeb`

Comment: puede ser algo que no este en el `phpinfo()`?

Comment: No creo. Es la ruta la que debe estar mal. Revisa lo que imprime esto: **`echo __DIR__.'/config/';`**  y verifica si el archivo está realmente en la ruta que se imprime.

Comment: Desde `phpinfo()` encontre la ruta que es `/home/sitioweb/public_html` lo cual yo solo utilizaba `public_html`. Gracias por la ayuda!